Garage front wall is a portal frame or shear wall?
I’m having trouble interpreting the plans for the garage entrance.   A detail of a post beam hardware is throwing me off.
The garage wall is flanked on either end with 3-0 shear walls as detailed in the foundation plan.  However the framing plan calls out a post / beam connection hardware (simpson ECCQ/similar), so should I frame this as a portal frame with straps? or something else.   The beam for the garage door is a regular 4×12 DF. and ceiling height is 11-6.


Thanks

Have you asked the architect? Are you the homeowner building this yourself, or a contractor building for someone else? The former is perfectly acceptable here, the latter is not, since this is a "DIY" site.
